# C# Passing string from one form to another

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms called, `Main` and `Kitchen`.

In `Main` I have a textbox called `detailName`, I need to pass the value of `detailName.Text` from `Main` to `Kitchen` to a `TextBox` called `orderBox`.

```
  Kitchen newKitchenForm = new Kitchen();
  newKitchenForm.OrderBox.Text = detailName.Text;
```

That is my code for it but it does not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Further information:

I'm programming a order food through touchscreen type of thing, so I want the thing that the client orders to be displayed to both the client and to the kitchen, hence the form name "Kitchen".

So after a button called "lockOrder_In" is pressed, I want the food they just chose to be shown to the person ordering and to the kitchen. Here is my code for that button.

```
private void lockOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dish_1.Text += Environment.NewLine + detailName.Text;
        Price_1.Text += Environment.NewLine + detailPrice.Text;

        // Show the order in the kitchen form

        Kitchen newKitchenForm = new Kitchen();

        newKitchenForm.ordersBox.Text = detailName.Text;
    }
```

I got the client side to work, but the person order is able to see what they ordered but on the other form "Kitchen" they are not. The food Name which is shown in "detailName.Text" in form "Main", is not displayed in "Kitchen" Form in "orderBox.Text".

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it does not seem to work"?

Comment: You want to pass the text to `orderBox` or to `OrderBox2`? Your question and code does not fit.

Comment: i think you are creating a new instance of your `Kitchen` form and trying to use that.  You need to use the same instance of the `Kitchen` that is currently being displayed.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the issue you're having? Looking at this question, thefirst thing that I think to my self is: What technology is this on? WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF? The second one is: What is the context here? From those two lines of code I can't realize what's happening in you app...

Comment: There is no error, the text is just not displayed in the "Kitchens" Form.

Comment: You are creating a new form, but where are you showing it? If the form already exists, you need to keep a global reference to it and instead of creating a new one, update the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as a parameter in the Kitchen form constructor or define a public property in Kitchen and set its value to the textbox's text property.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily by creating an instance of Form 1 in Form 2. This is one of the approach.

Follow the steps:

In Form 1 : Make sure that your control is public.

```
eg: txtForm1.Text = "Bangalore";
```

In Form 2 :

Step 1: Create an instance of Form 1 globally. If the instance is created locally the value contained by the control cannot be accessed, only null value will be returned even the data has been populated to it.

Step 2 : Retrieve the control's value by Form 1's instance.

```
 eg: Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
     string Form1Value = frm1.txtForm1.Text
```

for more details [MSDN Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/d925077a-d013-481b-8ce5-3d1af1cd924e/how-to-pass-values-from-one-form-to-another)

Comment: The sample code in "step 2" is exactly what you advise against in "step 1", creating a new instance of the form.  That won't work at all because it's not accessing the right instance.  And why make a "global" form, why not just pass the value on the constructor to the second form?  Or pass a reference to the first form in the constructor?  Or make a public property on the second form?  Don't just make everything global whenever you need slightly higher scope of values, that's going to cause a *lot* of problems.